# Using face-api.js how do I flip the pixels horizontally to achieve a mirror image?

Tags: javascript, scale, translate, webcam-capture, face-api

I'm working on a project using my webcam and facial recognition and I need the video feed to be a mirror image, not flipped horizontally which is how it is by default. I figured out how to flip the video so it appears mirrored using CSS, but the actual pixels and facial tracking is still flipped horizontally. Here is the code I have, I know I need to translate and scale the canvas but everything I've tried hasn't worked.

```js
const video = document.getElementById('video')

Promise.all([
  faceapi.nets.tinyFaceDetector.loadFromUri('/models'),
  faceapi.nets.faceLandmark68Net.loadFromUri('/models'),
  faceapi.nets.faceRecognitionNet.loadFromUri('/models'),
  faceapi.nets.faceExpressionNet.loadFromUri('/models')
]).then(startVideo)

function startVideo() {
  navigator.getUserMedia(
    { video: {} },
    stream => video.srcObject = stream,
    err => console.error(err)
  )
}

video.addEventListener('play', () => {
  canvas = faceapi.createCanvasFromMedia(video)
  document.body.append(canvas)
  const displaySize = { width: video.width, height: video.height }
  faceapi.matchDimensions(canvas, displaySize)
  setInterval(async () => {
    const detections = await faceapi.detectAllFaces(video, new faceapi.TinyFaceDetectorOptions()).withFaceLandmarks().withFaceExpressions()
    const resizedDetections = faceapi.resizeResults(detections, displaySize)
    canvas.getContext('2d').clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
    faceapi.draw.drawDetections(canvas, resizedDetections)
    faceapi.draw.drawFaceLandmarks(canvas, resizedDetections)
    faceapi.draw.drawFaceExpressions(canvas, resizedDetections)
  }, 100)
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script defer src="face-api.min.js"></script>
  <script defer src="script.js"></script>
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      width: 100vw;
      height: 100vh;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
    }

    canvas {
      position: absolute;
    }

    /* flips the video horizontally so its accurate with your movements left and right */
    video {
      -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
      transform: scaleX(-1);
    }

  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <video id="video" width="1600" height="800" autoplay muted></video>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add in `canvas` CSS element also the flipping code (transform):

```
canvas {
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
    transform: scaleX(-1);
}
```

Then, the `canvas` element is flipped as the `video` element.

Note: this solution only works if your canvas doesn't contains text or other content that may be susceptible of get the mirror effect (see flipped). In that case, you must map the box(es) coordinates returned, horizontally.